# Turn off XPCE in SWI-Prolog

Tags: emacs, swi-prolog, xpce

I'd like to get the output of `apropos/1` and `help/1` etc. inside my Emacs buffer, instead of an XPCE window. I'm using SWI-Prolog under Linux.

What I have tried:

- Setting flags in the init file (`~/.plrc`):

  ```
  :- set_prolog_flag(gui, false).
  :- set_prolog_flag(xpce, false).
  ```
- Calling `swipl` with the `--nopce` flag (a wild guess looking at `/usr/lib/swi-prolog/xpce.rc`)
- `ssh localhost`, effectively emulating a terminal-only machine, which worked, but there must be a better solution...

And yes, I could just uninstall the `swi-prolog-x` package, but I may want to write GUI programs in the future. Ideally I would like to turn off the GUI only for the documentation / debugging.

**EDIT:**

I've found out part of the solution: the goals `online_help:give_help/1` and `online_help:give_apropos` seem to be what I need. I just need to re-hook these onto `help` and `apropos`, maybe via `prolog:help_hook/1`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[~]# unset DISPLAY

swipl --nopce
```

This a an undocumented flag...  Normally it is only used when *building* the system/